# Secondary sorting not working correctly for Elasticsearch documents

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm using Nest to retrieve data with different document types from an index. The documents are: contact and invoice. Currently the search descriptor sorts on two different fields. I've simplified the search descriptor to show how the sorting works:

```
    descriptor.Index(index)
        .Type(esDocumentTypes)
        .Query(q => q
            .Bool(bq => bq
                .Must(BuildMustClause(typeCodesForFilters))
                .Should(BuildShouldClause(typeCodesForFilters))
                .MustNot(BuildMustNotClause())
                .MinimumShouldMatch(1)
            )
                )
        .Routing(RoutingValue)
        .Size(DefaultMaxResults)
         .TrackScores()
         .Sort(st => st.Field(f => f.Field("_score").Descending()))
         .Sort(st => st.Field(f2 => f2.Field("invoiceDate").Descending().IgnoreUnmappedFields()))
```

The document type contact doesn't contain a field for "invoiceDate" (only the invoice document does). I find that when this second sort is added it messes up with the sorting for score with contacts (but not invoices that contains this information) i.e. just having the single _score sorting returns the highest ranking document in contacts, but adding the secondary sorting field ("invoiceDate") now results in the highest score contact document not being returned in order.

When I replace the secondary search field with one that is actually in contact (e.g. contactName) then I find that the correctly ordered results are returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Missing` parameter of Sort. You can provide a default value of `0` which have `invoiceDate` missing.

Syntax would be somewhat like

```
.Sort(st => st.Field(f2 => f2.Field("invoiceDate").Descending().Missing(0).IgnoreUnmappedFields()))
```

Read more about Missing [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_missing_values).

Hope this helps for you!!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. There isn't a Missing method but I tried using MissingValue (which accepts a string) and it doesn't work. I tried both a string of "0" and DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: Hey I might  be missing on the syntax. I know JSON query version of above. May be `https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/sort-usage.html#_fluent_dsl_example_19` this can help you.

Comment: Thaks. That url you pasted doesn't resolve unfortunately (neither does the hyper link included in the first post you posted titled "here")

Comment: I am so sorry about the url. Can you please see this  and search for `missing` word on this page . https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/sort-usage.html

Comment: I have also updated url in question. Please see if it helps

Comment: There's `MissingValue()` but as you've found, it only supports `string`. I'll open an issue to address

Comment: I have tested it with elastic search using Java API. There is method missing which takes an object. Not sure about nest..

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input. I tried:

    `.Sort(st => st.Field(f => f.Field("_score").Descending())).Sort(st => st.Field(f2 =>f2.Field("invoiceDate").IgnoreUnmappedFields().MissingLast().
                 Descending()))`

And it's messing up the order of the return values.

Comment: I'm thinking of a work around where I make two API calls to ES in parallel where each queries the different document type and where only the invoice document has the additional search field sorting invoiceDate applied to it. And I could then combine their results. Although this approach is a bit cumbersome.

Comment: The amount of changes required to do each of the document calls in parallel will be too big of a change to the codebase. Anyone else have any suggestion of a work around i could use to get this duel sorting working on the index?